# How to add image to SVG with Bobril

Tags: javascript, image, typescript, svg, bobril

I am trying to add image to SVG with Bobril, but this code doesn't work:

```
{
    tag: 'svg',
    children: {
        tag: 'image',
        attrs: {
            'xlink:href': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bobris/Bobril/master/logo.png',
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        }
    }
}
```

Image tag is added to the page, but no image is shown. When I copy the element in Chrome's DevTools and paste it once again, the image is shown. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 'xlink:href' use just href.

xlink:href is deprecated since SVG 2

Comment: True reason why it works is this line https://github.com/Bobris/Bobril/blob/e642be6b19b1a04a0990e48dd3806990f3eab76d/package/index.ts#L450